# Polymorphic definition of the equality in Isabelle/ZF doesn't seem to work

Tags: sml, isabelle

If the definition of equality in Isabelle/ZF (more precisely, IFOL) is there:

```
axiomatization
  eq :: ‹['a, 'a] ⇒ o›  (infixl ‹=› 50)
where
  refl: ‹a = a› and
  subst: ‹a = b ⟹ P(a) ⟹ P(b)›
```

How can I prove this:

```
lemma qu:
  fixes C::‹i⇒o›
  shows ‹C = C›
oops
```

It's not even typechecked! And the "eq" has polymorphic type! How can it be?

Of course we can define equality of classes:

```
definition
  eqc  :: "[(i⇒o),(i⇒o)]=>o" where
    "eqc(A,B) == ∀x. A(x) ⟷ B(x)"
```

but the question is about enabling the (adhoc?) polymorphism in Isabelle.

Answer (score 0):

The equality sign "=" denotes equality of **sets** in Isabelle/ZF. The equivalence of predicates is denoted `\<equiv>` which renders as "≡" in Isabelle/Jedit and the proof document. The following illustrates this:

```
theory Scratch imports ZF.equalities

begin

lemma A: shows "C = C" by simp 

lemma B: shows "C \<equiv> C" by simp

lemma C: 
  assumes "P \<equiv> Q" 
  shows "\<forall>x. P(x) \<longleftrightarrow> Q(x)" using assms by auto

lemma D: 
  assumes "P \<equiv> Q" 
  shows "\<forall>x y. P(x,y) \<longleftrightarrow> Q(x,y)" using assms by auto

end
```

This is how it looks like from a user's perspective, I don't know how is it internally implemented.